# Conditional density of X given if X is atleast t

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a positive random variable with probability density funcion $f_X(x)$ and $Y := 1_{[X \ge t]}$ for a fixed $t$.

I am interested in the conditional density $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

Using Bayes' Theorem:

$f_{X|Y}(x|Y=y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)}{f_Y(y)} = \begin{cases}\frac{f_{Y|X}(0|x)f_X(x)}{f_Y(0)}  = \frac{1_{[x < t]}f_X(x)}{p(Y = 0)} = \frac{1_{[x < t]}f_X(x)}{\int_{0}^t f_X(x) dx} &\text{when }Y = 0\\ 
\frac{f_{Y|X}(1|x)f_X(x)}{f_Y(1)} = \frac{1_{[x \ge t]}f_X(x)}{p(Y = 1)} = \frac{1_{[x \ge t]}f_X(x)}{1-\int_{0}^t f_X(x) dx}&\text{when }Y = 1
\end{cases} $

Considering the discrete case this makes sense. But using $f_Y(y) = p(Y = y)$ feels very illegal. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random variable $Y$ has no PDF so the use of $f_Y(y)$ is actually illegal.

Personally I would go for:

- $P\left(X\leq x\mid Y=0\right)=\frac{P\left(X\leq x,Y=0\right)}{P\left(Y=0\right)}=\begin{cases}
  \frac{F_{X}\left(x\right)}{F_{X}\left(t\right)} & \text{if }x<t\\
  1 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$
- $P\left(X\leq x\mid Y=1\right)=\frac{P\left(X\leq x,Y=1\right)}{P\left(Y=1\right)}=\begin{cases}
  \frac{F_{X}\left(x\right)-F_{X}\left(t\right)}{1-F_{X}\left(t\right)} & \text{if }x\geq t\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

Then the corresponding PDF's can be described as:

- $f_{X|Y=0}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{f_{X}\left(x\right)}{F_{X}\left(t\right)} & \text{if }x<t\\
  1 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$
- $f_{X|Y=1}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{f_{X}\left(x\right)}{1-F_{X}\left(t\right)} & \text{if }x\geq t\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

This agrees with your end result.

Comment: Agree with @drhab, this is the right way to look at it. Sometimes we get so tangled up in the formalisms we lose track of the fundamentals.